# Offload Media Library to other domain on a different server

Tags: uploads, media-library, subdomains, cloud

How is it possible to change the media storage of Wordpress to a subdomain on a different server. The main domain `example.com` running on a server pointing to IP `192.168.0.1` and I've created a subdomain `subdomain.example.com` running on a different server pointing to IP `192.168.1.1` which in return has 2 different home directory URL

example.com `/home/example`
subdomain.example.com `/home/example2`

I'm clarifying those points because `upload_path` and `upload_url_path` works great when the domain and subdomain runs on the same server however here the case is different. Is there a plugin that can authenticate the FTP credentials and manage to resolve this changing the storage to external URL as if it's Cloud Storage from Gooogle or AWS?